# Laravel 5.6 - Stripe error: You did not set a valid publishable key

Tags: stripe-payments, vue-component, laravel-5.6

I'm e-learning to develop an e-learning platform, I don't have experience with Vue or Stripe so that's why I can't solve it. When I tried to do a test transaction, the app shown the message "You didn't set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key".

Initially the "striple_key" to the form didn't recognize the env value,so I tried with "php artisan config:cache" & "php artisan config:clear", then the form recognized the values again but the error still there.

The .env() file:

```
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_uyVT3UaDsNwLN4HmGwN0wnOx00lO3R87gO
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_ityGTiVn7QxLzfnx08tbUY8B00i6K0CZlU
```

The config/services.php file:

```
 'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
 ]
```

The Vue component called "StripeForm":

```
<template>
   <stripe-checkout
      button="Suscribirme"
      buttonClass="btn btn-course"
      :stripe--key="stripe_key"
      :product="product"
   >
   </stripe-checkout>
</template>

<script>
   import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe'

   export default {
       components: {

           StripeCheckout
       },
       props:{

           stripe_key: '',
           name: '',
           amount: '',
           description:''

       },
       computed:{

           product (){
               return{

                   name: this.name,
                   amount: parseFloat(this.amount),
                   description: this.description

               }
           }

       }
   }
</script>
```

The method "processSubscription" in the controller "SubscriptionController":

```
$token = request('stripeToken');

try{
    if (request()->has('coupon')){
        request()->user()->newSubscription('main', request('type'))
           ->withCoupon(request('coupon'))->create($token);
    }else{
        request()->user()->newSubscription('main',request('type'))
           ->create($token);
         }

    }catch(\Exception $exception){
        $error = $exception->getMessage();
        return back()->with('message', ['danger', $error]);
    }
```

The Subscription's routes

```
Route::prefix('subscriptions')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/plans', 'SubscriptionController@plans')
     ->name('subscriptions.plans');
    Route::post('/process_subscription', 
     'SubscriptionController@processSubscription')
     ->name('subscriptions.process_subscriptions');
```

---

I'll be thankful of any help :)

Comment: Are those your actual Stripe keys? If so, you might want to reset them ;)

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but when updated the keys there was no change, even after to clean the cache, 
just after some minutes the app started to work correctly. Thanks a lot :)